# Would an "index of accessibility to radial highways" be considered discrete numerical data or ordinal categorical data?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, statistics, data-science

I am currently conducting data exploration on the "load_boston" dataset from scikit-learn, and one of the attributes is titled 'RAD', which, according to the dataset docs, represents an "index of accessibility to radial highways".

The column only contains discrete integers from 1 to 24, and many rows share the same value. I'm leaning towards saying it's ordinal categorical, since I think 'index of accessibility' means that the values don't necessarily represent a number but perhaps a ranking. But then again, maybe I'm missing something. Any thoughts?

Comment: From the Wikipedia page titled "Transportation in Boston": "Expressways and major arterial roads in and around Greater Boston are laid out with two circumferential expressways: Interstate 495 and Route 128. The circumferential routes are bisected by several radial highways that were planned to start in downtown Boston and proceed outward from the city."

Comment: In https://bookdown.org/egarpor/PM-UC3M/lm-ii-lab-boston.html a similar dataset is mentioned, pertaining to housing in Boston. It is mentioned that the variable `rad` pertains to "accessibility to radial highways", and that a "larger index denotes better accessibility". Based on this, I'd say that in the scikit-learn dataset `RAD` is a discrete ordinal variable.

Comment: @Jasha thanks, this is exactly the definition I needed, however, I'm confused by "discrete ordinal". Is that different from "ordinal categorical"?

Comment: No difference. I was using the word "discrete" to refer to the fact that `RAD` takes only whole-number values (as opposed to e.g. a continuous variable taking on real-number values).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, an "index" (e.g. the [level of freedom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_freedom_indices) in a country, the accessibility to radial highways) is a *categorical* variable and more specifically, an *ordinal* one.

This [machine learning article](https://machinelearningmastery.com/one-hot-encoding-for-categorical-data/) delineates between *nominal* categorical variables such as color (red, green, or blue) and ordinal categorical variables such as placement (first, second, third).

> Nominal Variable (Categorical). Variable comprises a finite set of discrete values with **no relationship between values**.

> Ordinal Variable. Variable comprises a finite set of discrete values with a **ranked ordering between values**.

The key is the relationship between values - if one RAD value indicates greater highway accessibility than the other (e.g. a score of 5 vs 3), then it is ordinal.

Comment: the  'machine learning article' is getting to a  Promotional site...

Comment: @RSNboim You don't see the quoted paragraphs?